# How to create obtain aliased version of $f(t)$ by upsampling whenever $f(t)$ at every $t$ is available

Tags: fourier-analysis, signal-processing

Suppose there is original complex-valued $f(t)$ with $t$ ranging from $-\infty$ to $\infty$. It is possible obtain samples from original $f(t)$ at every $t$ with some negligible error.

If one downsamples $f(t)$ (with sampling interval $T$), one is effectively sampling from an aliased version $f_a(t)$ of $f(t)$. It is possible to reconstruct/interpolate samples of $f_a(t)$ at higher sampling rates by using downsampled samples, but this comes with heavy costs especially if upsampling ratio is very high.

Does full sampling access to original $f(t)$ aid in interpolation of $f_a(t)$?

Comment: do you know how to think sampling and interpolation in the Fourier domain ? (and thus how to prove the Shannon sampling theorem)

Comment: By downsample do you mean decimation? The difference being that dowsampling implies that a filter was applied to prevent aliasing. Also, it's not clear what you're asking. If you have the original signal, then what do you hope to gain from the aliased version?